# Count the fields not including the zero value of the fields in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008. I have an output like this:

```
  Customer    Total Amount         Jan     Feb    Mar    Apr    May    

   A           20000               1000    2000   5000     0    7000
   B           15000               5000    7000   3000     0     0
   C           18000               8000    5000    0     8000    0
   D           5000                5000      0     0       0     0
```

How can I make count the fields from Jan to May without the zero field value? So the output will be like this:

```
  Customer    Total Amount         Jan     Feb    Mar    Apr    May      Count   

   A           20000               1000    2000   5000     0    7000       4
   B           15000               5000    7000   3000     0     0         3
   C           18000               8000    5000    0     8000    0         3
   D           5000                5000      0     0       0     0         1
```

Thanks..

Comment: You have to make a conditional formula to put it in the count column. I can provide you with rough syntax. check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a formula for your Count columns something like this

```
IF {table.Jan} <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 +
IF {table.Feb} <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 +
IF {table.Mar} <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 +
IF {table.Apr} <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 +
IF {table.May} <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Comment: I think it would also be worth modifying to discount nulls too.


So: IF {table.Jan} = 0 or  isnull({table.Jan}) THEN 0 ELSE 1
ect.. ect..


I think this is a little more robust

Comment: @AlecHenderson_v1.00 In order to handle nulls (which is always a good idea) you would need to _first_ check if it is null, eg: `if isnull({table.Jan}) or {table.Jan}=0 then 0 else 1` Otherwise, your formula will result in an exception upon encountering a null and won't return anything.

Comment: I Tried this but it's only showing 0 or 1 value. I forgot to mentioned that the output is arranged by group (by Customer).